# How to consume a growing hdfs directory as a streaming source in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

We have a time-partitioned hdfs directory which is growing all the time. Is there any way to consistently consume this directory as a stream using apache flink?

Answer (score 1):

Flink can monitor a directory and ingest files when they are moved into that directory; maybe that's what you are looking for. See [the PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY option for readfile](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources) in the documentation.

Comment: Hi, David. We have a nested directory structure which has multiple layers. The problem here is that the upper directory contains huge amount of files(partitioned by hour) which is not suitable for the PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY option for readfile. I want to know is there any way to consistently add/delete hourly directories to our data source? Thanks.

Comment: I think you might find it more straightforward to dynamically create a new (batch) job to ingest each hour.

Comment: Is there a reason why this can’t be addressed with a path filter that dynamically updates the path given the current time? Will this allow flink to manage with this velocity of file uploads?